# RPM high in fifth gear

Tags: rpm, peugeot-308

I'm a newbie to driving and I'm in need of advice for my Peugeot 308. It's the 2009 five door hatch back - 1.4 petrol.

Usually the RPM's of the car are between 1500 - 2200, but when i shift to fifth gear, the rpms go to 3000+, and when i'm driving at 70mph on the motorway it's 6000+.

I'm just curious if there is anything i should be concered about, or is this perfectly normal for this car? The car jolts a bit when i shift from fourth to fifth, and i'm not sure if that is of any relevance.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an automatic or standard shift?

Comment: Hi! Standard shift

Comment: Do the RPMs increase when you shift from 4th to 5th?

Comment: Yep. They go up and not down (unlike the other gears)

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I'm betting you're actually shifting not into 5th, but back into 3rd. This could be caused from a shifter linkage issue or from a problem within the transmission itself.

Comment: Some shift systems have a rather strong spring which biases the stick position to 3rd-4th gear, in a left-to-right sense. It might need more of a deliberate sideways movement than you are giving it, to get it into 5th gear, than the car you learnt to drive in. I remember when a friend let me take the wheel of his Alfasud, I kept embarrassing myself with fluffed gear changes, for this reason.

Comment: Thanks both, this actually makes a lot of sense! I'll get this checked out asap.